# Combining fields to insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am having issues with this. I am trying to make it so these fields combine, one with - and one without to insert into a database

```
$daters = $_POST['11']." ". $_POST['22']." ". $_POST['33']; 
$dater = $_POST['11']." - ". $_POST['22']." - ". $_POST['33'];
```

---

```
    <?php

                     //  if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
                     if (isset($_POST['submit2']))

{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","rabbitju_rjziond","r4bb1t");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("rabbitju_rjreservation", $con);


$daters = $_POST['11']." ". $_POST['22']." ". $_POST['33']; 
$dater = $_POST['11']." - ". $_POST['22']." - ". $_POST['33'];



//Writes the to the server 

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reservation__date` (`reservation_id`, `reservation_date`) 
VALUES
 ('daters', '$dates')") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"6\">";  
mysql_close($con);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `('daters', '$dates')` you forgot a `$` on daters and do you get any error messages? if so post the complete error message for us to help you.

Comment: You also misspelled `$dater` as `$dates`. You're asking for trouble using variable names that are so similar.

Comment: Not to mention form fields with meaningless names like `11`, `22`, and `33`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reservation__date` (`reservation_id`, `reservation_date`) VALUES ('$daters', '$dates')") or die(mysql_error());
```

There was no $ before 'daters'

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. The $ sign you forgot to add for reservation_id value.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reservation__date` (`reservation_id`, `reservation_date`) VALUES ('".$daters."', '".$dates."')");
```